# VACUUM FULL alternatives on Windows PGSQL (pg_repack, pg_squeeze, ... )

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

I have a big table which needs a Vacuum full, but I don't have enough disk space.
I was looking online and came across some: pg_repack, pg_squeeze, ...

Am I mistaken or are all these extensions Linux only? Are there similar extensions for Postgresql running on Windows?
I'm looking for an extensions which can remove bloat (deleted tuples, ... ) from a table without locking the table like Vacuum full does.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to see if you can compile any of those extensions on Windows. [pgcompacttable](https://github.com/dataegret/pgcompacttable)  is written in Perl, so maybe it runs on Windows as well

Comment: I think those don't do what you want anyway, they still take up extra space while the table is being rewritten.

Comment: It is not obvious to me how to make pgcompacttable  run on Windows, but you can at least run it from Linux but point it at a db server running on Windows.

Comment: In other words, mainly all extensions are linux only? That's a bummer.
Only thing I can do is dump the table to an other server and restore it in production. But with a table of this size, I really don't know how long the dump / restore will take. I can't put them offline for days...